# (discord.py) How can I make it so my bot that doesn't reply to other commands until the current command is finished

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a discord bot written in python. It doesn't do much, however if you spam commands while it is in the middle to replying to another command, it freaks out. is there a way to make it refuse other commands until it has finished with the current process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some global variable "ready" and just allow to run commands if ready is true?
At start of command set ready to false and at the end to true.

Comment: I'm actually ashamed I didn't think of that in the first place, thanks for the help so far it works very well.

Comment: If that answer is enough for your question, make sure accepting it as an answer and maybe also giving an upvote. ;)